# Is it correct to use an index that features INCLUDE of all columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

While debugging a SQL query, SQL Server Dev Studio suggested that I have to create index like:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_MY_INDEX ON T_EVENT (F_ORIGINAL_ID, F_EVENT_SEQUENCE_NO) 
     INCLUDE (F_USER_ID,  F_REVISION_NO, ... <about 30-40 columns>)
```

So, in `INCLUDE` it suggested to have a massive number of columns.

While I do know that it is a bad design to use all columns in the main index clause, what would be the drawbacks to use all fields in `INCLUDE`? Or is it completely OK (performance and optimization-wise) to have such an index with many columns after `INCLUDE`?

Comment: Does the SQL query start with "SELECT *"?

Comment: The "index suggestion" feature of SQL Server Management Studio is known to have its severe weaknesses - at times suggesting indices that already exist, or suggesting these kinds of "over the top" indices - those do **not** make sense, do **NOT** just blindly implement whatever that tool suggests!

Comment: Yes i mean selects, but speed of insert is also important

Comment: Shortly it is not a good practice. If the statement produces that suggestion is the ONLY statement (quite unlikely) running against this table then yes, it would help more or less at the cost of double table size at all times. For other data alter statements (insert/updates and deletes) simply means double time. For selects that do not use that index you still has the storage cost.

Answer (score 2):

The downside is the storage and maintenance. The data would be duplicated and the index updated whenever the underlying data are changed. The upside is the index will avoid the key lookup in the plan in order to retrieve the other columns needed by the query.

Keep in mind this index is a suggestion, not a recommendation. It might be better change the existing clustered index to non-clustered (perhaps with selectively included columns to optimize queries) and make the suggested index the clustered index. Whether or not this is appropriate depends on your workload and query mix. A good indexing strategy requires a holistic approach rather than focusing on a single query/index.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what a clustered index does.  So, if the table does not have clustered index, you can create one using the relevant columns for the index.

Is including all the columns a good idea?  I would say that as a *general practice*, it is not a good idea.  But there are definitely some specific cases it is useful.  Basically, the index is a covering index for any query on the table.  So if the index is used, there are no references to the data pages.

There are downsides:

- Inserts, updates, and deletes are slower.  Even updates on non-index keys affect the index.

  - The index is "as big as" the table (actually a bit bigger, because there is additional overhead in the index).
- The larger index has cascading effects, in terms of maintaining the database -- such as longer backup/recover  and longer defragmenting.